How can I calculate the RSI for Bitcoin in Excel?
How can I calculate the Relative Strength Index (RSI) for Bitcoin in Excel? What formulas or steps should I follow to accurately compute the RSI using historical price data, and how can I implement this in an Excel spreadsheet?

Could you please highlight in your question, how calculating the RSI for Bitcoin works differently than for other assets? If it’s all the same as for any other financial market, I don’t think this is on-topic here.

My question is how to do this in Excel. Is this off topic for this forum?

People don’t usually engage much with these sort of topics, and we don’t accept topics concerning investment advice here in the first place. Unless there is a specific reason why RSI is different for Bitcoin, your question might be more likely to get engagement on money.stackexchange.com which already has 59 questions about RSI.

I got it. Thank you! Sorry for the off-topic, I'm new here.
